# usage of GrailsApplicationAware

Tags: grails

According to the [docs](http://grails.org/doc//2.1.3/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/support/aware/GrailsApplicationAware.html) the `GrailsApplicationAware` interface is a

> Convenience interface that can be implemented by classes that are registered by plugins.

So presumably a Spring bean that implements this interface can use it to get an instance of `GrailsApplication`. But can other objects implement this interface for the same purpose? It's not clear to me what is meant by

> classes that are registered by plugins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works the same as standard Spring interfaces such as `ApplicationContextAware` - any bean (whether implicitly registered as an artefact or explicitly registered in `resources.xml`, `resources.groovy` or a plugin's `doWithSpring`) that implements the interface will have its `setGrailsApplication(GrailsApplication ga)` method called automatically by the framework without needing to explicitly name it as a property or turn on autowiring.

For beans that are set up to do autowiring (e.g. Grails services) you don't need to implement `GrailsApplicationAware`, you only need to provide a `setGrailsApplication` method (which a Groovy property definition `def grailsApplication` will create for you) and it will be autowired because the `GrailsApplication` is registered as a bean named `grailsApplication`.  Or of course you can inject the bean explicitly

```
doWithSpring = {
  myPluginBean(MyPluginBean) {
    grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
  }
}
```

Comment: so "classes that are registered by plugins" means "spring beans or Grails artefacts"? Is it true that all Grails artefacts are also Spring beans (though not necessarily singleton beans)?

Comment: @Don technically I don't think there's any rule saying that an arbitrary artefact _must_ correspond to a Spring bean but in practice all the standard ones do (domains, controllers, services, taglibs, bootstrap, quartz jobs, ...).